# How to covert a vector of bytes to a byte array in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do this, but doesn't work:

```
fn foo() {
    let v = b"Hello".to_vec();
    let a = v.as_bytes();
}
```

I'm getting:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `as_bytes` found for struct `Vec<u8>` in the current scope
  --> foo
   |
26 |     let a = v.as_bytes();
   |               ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Vec<u8>`
```

Comment: Why do you bother to convert it? can't `vec<u8>` satisfy your use case? And it's mostly not recommanded because `[u8]` requires an explicit static size during the compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't wish to write the `[u8; N]` type, you can choose not '.to_vec()' in the beginning and use `*b"string"` to obtain the byte array directly without type annotation.

```rust
struct Pack {
    data: Box<[u8]>,
}

fn foo() {
    let mut p = Pack {
        data: Box::new(*b"Hello!"),
    };
    p.data = Box::new(*b"Bye!");
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let v = *b"Hello!";

    let boxed_v = Box::new(*b"Hello!");

    assert_eq!(
        format!("{} {} {} {} {}", v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4]),
        "72 101 108 108 111"
    );

    assert_eq!(
        format!(
            "{} {} {} {} {}",
            boxed_v[0], boxed_v[1], boxed_v[2], boxed_v[3], boxed_v[4]
        ),
        "72 101 108 108 111"
    )
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Rust, an array has its length encoded in its type – e.g., `[u8; 5]` – it is a compile-time property, whereas a `Vec`'s length is a run-time property. Every byte array, `[u8; N]`, implements [`TryFrom<Vec<u8>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#impl-TryFrom%3CVec%3CT%2C%20A%3E%3E) , so `Vec<u8>` implements `TryInto<[u8; N]>` as a result. Therefore, you can use `try_into()` on a `Vec<u8>` to convert it into a byte array:

```
let a: [u8; 5] = v.try_into().unwrap();
```

Note that [`TryInto::try_into()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html) returns a `Result` for the reason explained above: the mismatch of the nature of the length property of a `Vec` and an array – run-time and compile-time, respectively.

---

**Why not convert the `Vec<u8>` into a byte slice instead?**

Keep in mind that you can easily create a byte slice (i.e., `&[u8]`) from a `Vec<T>`. A `Vec<u8>` *deref coerces* into `[u8]` as it implements `Deref<Target=[u8]>`:

```
let v = b"Hello".to_vec();
let a: &[u8] = &v;
```

You can also call [`as_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_slice) on a `Vec<u8>`:

```
let a = v.as_slice();
```

This may be what you want because you are probably using a `Vec` to be able to change the length at run time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to covert a vector of bytes to a byte array:

```
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<u8> = vec![44u8, 99u8];
    println!("{v:?}");
    let a: [u8; 2] = v.try_into().unwrap();
    println!("{a:?}");
}
```

The size of the array needs to be known at compile time though.